# Android - Remote Service - Unable to show Dialog box

Tags: android, database, android-alertdialog

i am developing reminder application for taking tablet. I just store list of tablets to be taken on everyday in database with `date and time`. Everyday, my application should check, is there any tablet to be taken on this particular `date` ( today) if so, it has to fetch the time to show that tablet details. when a particular time comes, it has to show dialog box which contains list of tablets from db.

To do this i am using Remote service which will get system current date and check with database. i have to show dialog box( shows list of tablet details from db).
in remote service i have thread which runs every 10 sec to check for current date and match with db date. now i am unable to show `AlertBox` to show the task with description.

how to show the AlertBox in Remote Service.
i tried in this way....
 when i create alertbox, i need to pass Context as param, it shows

```
 android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException:....
```

Is it correct way? or from remote service, shall I call activity which shows dialogbox?

How to solve my problem.

Comment: You should provide the full stack. But the problem is that you are technically accessing a non existent UI in the foreground from a background service. You could try to use the application context by using whatever context you are passing to the AlertDialog and calling getApplicationContext on it and use that instead. However the foreground part you still need to resolve. check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int, android.app.Notification) if just using the ApplicationContext doesn't suffice. Basically you need a context that can hold a view.

Answer (score 0):

A service doesn't have  any UI elements, so can't show a dialog box.  You can either call an activity that does have a UI (your suggestion) or it might be better to create a notification which is the preferred option for Android alerts.

Comment: fine. i call notification from service like these